# How can I read Files from Inter or External Storage (SD Card) in app using android studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, file-manager

I am making a file manager app, I started with reading files of the storage by using the following code but the App crashes on opening I dont know why, I didnt find any error in it. Please give any helpful suggestion.

Manifest -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="read.files"
    android:installLocation="auto">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Main Activity XML -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

And JAVA -

```
package read.files;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

    private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        ListDir(root);
    }
    void ListDir(File f) {
        File[] files = f.listFiles();
        fileList.clear();
        for (File file : files){
            fileList.add(file.getPath());
        }
        ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
        setListAdapter(directoryList);
    }
}
```

Actually I saw this from a youtube video I did all the thing correctly but I dont know the app opens for a second and crashes. I tried many other methods also but nothing helped......

EDIT
Got my mistake at fileList.add(file.getPath());
To fileList.add(file.getName());

Comment: You have a NullPointerException clearly visible in the logcat. Please post the relevant lines. And that path is not from sd card. You can also remove the xml codes as they are irrelevant.

Comment: Well I am a beginner so I don't know much about java and app development.

Comment: Then now is the time to solve tis and learn to use the logs in the logcat. In Android Studio click at Logcat in the left down corner.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this line to the Android Manifest File

`android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`

This is used to read Shared Storage apart from the app's private storage. Read [this](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-the-scoped-storage-in-android) if you are curious to know more...

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...

Edit: As @blackapps mentioned, this is necessary for Android Q and up.

So add this `tools:targetApi="q"` in `AndroidManifest`

Comment: You forgot to tell that this only works for Android Q/10.